# JQuery Image Slideshow Repeat

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have made a slideshow consisting of three images.I now want to repeat exactly the same thing but using different images. image3.jpg, image4.jpg and image5.jpg.

Can anyone help?

The HTML is:

```
<div id="slideshow">
 <div id="slideshowWindow">

    <div class="slide">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" />
    </div><!--/slide-->

    <div class="slide">
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" />
    </div><!--/slide-->

    <div class="slide">
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg" />
    </div><!--/slide-->

</div><!--/slideshowWindow-->
</div><!--/slideshow-->
```

The CSS is:

```
#slideshow {
position:relative;
top:10px;
left:80px;
margin-bottom:400px;
}

#slideshow #slideshowWindow {
width:500px;
height:95px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}

#slideshow #slideshowWindow .slide {
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:500px; 
height:95px;
float:left;
position:relative;
}
```

And the jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var currentPosition = 0;
    var slideWidth = 500;
    var slides = $('.slide');
    var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
    var slideShowInterval;
    var speed = 10000;


    slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);

    slides.wrapAll('<div id="slidesHolder"></div>')

    slides.css({ 'float' : 'left' });

    $('#slidesHolder').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);


    function changePosition() {
        if(currentPosition == numberOfSlides - 1) {
            currentPosition = 0;
        } else {
            currentPosition++;
        }
        moveSlide();
    }


    function moveSlide() {
            $('#slidesHolder')
              .animate({'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)});
    }

});
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the actual problem? Nothing specifically looks incorrect but it'd be easier if I knew what was wrong. Theres a missing semicolon after wrapAll but it should still work I think

Comment: Hi I.m probably being naive here. But I want to make an identical slideshow but with different images and placed in a slightly different place on the page. If this is a simple CSS issue please can you help.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to duplicate on the same page with what you have will be an ordeal, you'll need to change the variable names and functions so they don't conflict, for example as you add slideshows you could add numbers to the different id's, variables (and functions/classes):

```
slides.wrapAll('<div id="slidesHolder"></div>');
slides2.wrapAll('<div id="slidesHolder2"></div>');
slides3.wrapAll('<div id="slidesHolder3"></div>');
```

Kind of a hassle but theres other ways (Object Oriented approach). Jeff Way has a great intro course to jQuery if you have time, worth doing the courses "Obligatory Slider (First Stab)" and "Prototypal Inheritance and Refactoring the Slider"

https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/

**Without going into how:** Basically you'll create a `Slider` object which has it's own properties. Instead of making things like `slides` a variable and `moveSlides()` a function that *specifically* targets `#slidesHolder`, these things are essentially pieces of each one of these slideshow objects already. In other words, when you create a slideshow it will be an inherit all the functions and variables (methods and properties) for itself to use.

If you've never heard of or done this, it might sound like sorcery but, like I said, invest some time and do those tutorials (maybe just do them all). I was able to jump into PHP and just about do the same thing with OOP after grasping it in javascript first, so it's not just a javascript or jQuery thing.

Hope that helps, you can always stick to the first idea.